# dyld: Library not loaded Xcode11

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, frameworks, xcode11

When I tried to install my project on my phone there is an error : "dyld: Library not loaded:" and in the file "dyld`__abort_with_payload:" the thread 1. But on simulator everything is good. 
So I tried to remake the same project with test step by step. At the first it's working but when I install pods (because of Firebase) the error appear. (I install the app on 2 devices, and they crashed at the same time. Without update.) (It was working very well there is 4 days.)

I don't know if it's because of my Apple certification iOS or it's about firebase with the update to iOS 13.3.1 ? Or something else ?

I tried many things on different topic.

Someone has resolve this issue ? :D

Comment: can you provide a bit more of the stacktrace?

Comment: https://www.casimages.com/i/200202120426265913.png.html and https://www.casimages.com/i/200202120426646310.png.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can't use your free development account with frameworks on iOS 13.3.1, user "Valdani" in the [Apple Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/128435) got it to work by commenting the **use_frameworks!** line in the podfile then making a "pod install" and a "pod update"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issues.

I remplace use_frameworks! by use_modular_headers! in the pod file

Thanks for help